# When dragging the html element, content not included to the target also moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to implement the dragging of the element in html.
My code is following.
But when dragging the first row without clicking `My Menu`, it works correctly.
But when dragging the first row after displaying the `My Menu` by clicking that button, the second row also is showed.

> The second row is not included to the first one.
>   But when showing the dropdown menu and dragging, the second row is also moved.

What is the reason of this and how could I fix?

```js
$('.dropdown').click(function(){
 if($(this).hasClass('show')) $(this).removeClass("show");
  else $(this).addClass("show");
})
```

```css
.row{
  position:relative;  
  padding:4px 15px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.dropdown{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid red;
  
}

.menu{
  position:absolute;
  list-style:none;
  display:none;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.dropdown.show .menu{
  display:block;
}

.menu li{
  padding:5px 20px;  
  background:gray;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" draggable="true">
    This is the first row
    <span class="dropdown">
      My Menu
       <ul class="menu">
        <li>
           item1
        </li>
        <li>
           item2
        </li>      
      </ul>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row" draggable="true">
    This is the second row
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also attached images when dragging.
This case is when dragging after showing the dropdown menu
[image: This case is when dragging after showing the dropdown menu]

Here is [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7d3c4nv6/5/)